# How to use request and read urls from a txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im writing a piece of code where I have a list of urls in a file and Im using requests to go through the file and do a GET request and print the status code but from what i have written I am not getting any output

```
import requests
with open('demofile.txt','r') as http:
    for req in http:
     page=requests.get(req)
     print page.status_code
```

Comment: Should the for loop not be inside the with statement? Looks like you're missing a level of indentation

Comment: @scotty3785 oops my bad it was intended correctly made a mistake on the submission

Comment: `print page.status_code` gives an error for your tag [tag:python-3.x].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two problems, one is that you forgot to indent the lines after the `for` loop and the second one is that you failed to remove the last new lines `\n` (supposing that urls are separated in different lines)

```
import requests

with open('deleteme','r') as urls:
    for url in urls.readlines():
        req = url.strip()
        print(req)
        page=requests.get(req)
        print(page.status_code)
```

Comment: Just a small edit need to add page=requests.get("http://"+req) to avoid schema error now have to find a way to bypass SSL verifications

Comment: His syntax of using `for req in http:` is valid, but as you stated, you now have newlines to strip out.  An alternate way of doing this is:  `data = open('deleteme', 'r').read()` and then `for line in data.splitlines()` which will also get rid of the line-endings for you.  This would require the entire file's contents to reside in memory, unfortunately.  (Note:  In python 3.x, use `data = open('deleteme', 'r').read().decode('utf-8')`